# JQuery toggle images CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery to change the css of some images.

It works and changes the image css size when clicked.
The only issue is that when I click on the next image, the previous image stays 
with the new css toggle.

Is there a way that when I click on the next image, the previous image goes back to 
the original css.

I have included a jsfiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/hSFpp/

Here is the jquery code:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('thumb fullview')
});
```

You can see that each image you click stays large.

Thanks

Comment: this is close, but not does not toggle the larger image. http://jsfiddle.net/Resey/

Comment: ok. this works. http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/rqkDR/1/

Comment: why did you take away my best answer award?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle. I solved your issue. please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Resey/1/

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fullview').siblings().removeClass('fullview');
});
```

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu probably because you posted nearly 30 minutes after I had posted and answer, and the OP himself had already sorted it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `fullview` class from all other `img` elements, before adding it to the one which was clicked. Try this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('img').removeClass('fullview'); // remove class from all
    $(this).addClass('fullview'); // add class to clicked img
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hSFpp/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the class on `img` "fullview" and adding it to `$(this)` after.

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('img').removeClass('fullview');
    $(this).addClass('fullview');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samrap/hSFpp/8/)

**UPDATE:**

I realized that though we both solved the problem, clicking the large image didn't toggle it. I added a function for that in the following code:

```
if ( $('img').hasClass('fullview') ) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fullview');
});
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/samrap/hSFpp/10/)

Comment: Your update has an issue - click the same image twice and it no longer works.

Comment: Yea i realized that right away...I've been working on a solution

Comment: @samrap - thanks, but as Rory pointed out, it only works once. See the updated answer. I just need the toggleClass.