# How to change checkbox to image for deleting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, checkbox

I have a shopping cart form where the user can currently check a box beside the item they wish to remove and click a button to submit.

I want to change it so that there is a trash can icon instead of the check box that removes the corresponding shopping cart item when the image itself is clicked.

Here is the Jquery for the checkbox function:

```
function RemoveShoppingCartItem(rcuid, sFormName) 
{ 
var eForm = document.getElementsByName(sFormName)[0]; 
document.getElementById('rcuid').value = rcuid; 
eForm.action += "&Action=REMOVE"; 
eForm.submit(); 
}
```

And the code for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="9681" name="rcuid">
```

But the value changes for each box.

What exactly do I need to change to get the result I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a checkbox, use a link with an CSS image background. Hook up the event handler to the link and you can then change CSS class names on click to swap the image within your function.

Comment: Do you have an example of what that might look like? I'm still a little bit confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165315/jquery-toggle-images-css

Comment: The only problem with that is I need the image to replace the checkbox right away, before anything is clicked. Then when the image is clicked, the shopping cart item should be remove just like if the checkbox was clicked and the form submitted.

I'm just unsure how to keep the delete function the same, since I'm switching input types.